# iOS9 Quick Action 画面遷移

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

iOS9以降から実装されているQuick Action(3D touch)を開発していますが
Appdelegate内から指定したViewController(StoryBoard)の呼び出しはできましたが
TabBarControllerの呼び出し方法がわかりません
rootViewControllerにStoryBoardで作成したTabBarをどのようにして追加すればよろしいのでしょうか?

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem
    completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler{
    if([shortcutItem.type compare:@"info.plistのTypeコード"] == NSOrderedSame) {

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewController;
            viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID名"];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

Comment: `UITabBarController`は、`UIViewController`のサブクラスだということは、おわかりですか？

Comment: 勉強不足でした
最初からrootViewControllerにUITabBarControllerを設定すればいいだけの話でしたね
コメントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました

```
UIViewController *viewController;
            viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID名"];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

から↓でUITabのIndex=1に割り当てているViewの表示ができました

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarControllerID名"];
tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Answer (score 0):

補足的な回答をします。「こういうこともできるよ」、「こうしたほうがいいんじゃないかなあ？」くらいの内容です。

`UIStoryboard`のメソッド`- (UIViewController *)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`の代わりに`- (UIViewController *)instantiateInitialViewController`を使うことを検討してください。
後者のメソッドは、Storyboard内の基底ViewControllerをインスタンス化して、返します。「基底」というのは、下図の矢印が付いているViewControllerのことで、Attributes Inspectorで、「Is Initial View Controller」にチェックが入っています。

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Storyboardの編集の意図に従ったインスタンス化をするというのが、このメソッドを使う意味です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます
是非とも参考にさせていただきます